# How to insert multiple records generated by select group by query

Tags: java, mysql

The actual SQL query which generates the result based on practicecode and count.As it contains multiple rows ,i am not able to insert it into database
using insert query.Please help me with this..??

**Query**

```
SELECT practicecode,COUNT(id) as ccr FROM  empi_ccr_export_preview  WHERE  delflag=0 GROUP BY practicecode
```

**Code**

```
public void doInsertData2(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, ResultSet rs92, ResultSet rs102,ResultSet rs112) 
    {
        try {
            while(rs9.next()&& rs10.next()&& rs11.next()) {
                Integer t1=Integer.parseInt(rs9.getString("practicecode"));
                Integer t2=Integer.parseInt(rs9.getString("ccr"));
                Integer t3=Integer.parseInt(rs10.getString("optinpracticecode"));
                Integer t4=Integer.parseInt(rs10.getString("lab"));
                Integer t5=Integer.parseInt(rs11.getString("sourcepracticecode"));
                Integer t6=Integer.parseInt(rs11.getString("doc"));

                try {
                    try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    } 
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    connection3 = DriverManager.getConnection("Driver details");
                    String query = "INSERT INTO practice_count (Community_ID,Practice_code,CCRcount,LABcount,DOCcount) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection3.prepareStatement(query);

                    preparedStmt.setInt(1, 101);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(2, t1);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(3, t2);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(4, t4);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(5, t6);

                    preparedStmt.execute();

                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Duplicate Entry Found"+e);  
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try , preparedStmt.executeUpdate();